# is 'Молодец! / молодцы́!' always a familiar expression?

Tags: выражения

I would like to know if the expression 'Молодец!' (or молодцы́!) in the context of 'good!', 'you did it right!', 'this is a great work!' ,'you accomplished a difficult work!' etc.... is always familiar or can be used for example with business partners in Russia ( and other ex-Ussr republics )

I have also the feeling that this term was strongly connected with the daily life in USSR, eg when a worker was well doing his(/her) job, doing his(/her) daily share of the work , when a project was done , etc....

if for example I use that term to say that some partners have done well their work and I have but informal business connections with them , could they consider that I am familiar with them? Or would it sounds natural?

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that `Молодцы!` cannot be used when addressing **one** person using respective plural `вы`. When addressing only **one** person you have to use `Молодец`, which sounds too informal.

When there are several persons you could use `Молодцы!` even for business partners.
But keep in mind, that this word sounds most naturally from a teacher, imho.

Comment: It's pretty natural to say 'Вы молоде́ц!' to one person, and it won't sound informal. There are [lots of examples of such usage](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB+%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6) in the National Corpus.

Comment: I agree, `Вы молодец!` sounds much better than `Молодец!`, but still my advice is to avoid this word in *business* communication.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty natural to say `Вы молоде́ц!` to one person, including one's business partner, and it won't sound informal or patronizing. If you address several people, then it is `Вы молодцы́!` There are [lots of examples of such usage](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB+%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6) in the National Corpus:

> ― Я слышал ваш разговор с моим коллегой. Вы молодец, конечно. Они в вас многое теряют, но только я должен сказать: я с вами всё-таки никак не согласен. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом, часть 2 (1943-1958)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB%20%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6&docid=84742)
>
> Но все хорошо, поздравляю вас с успехом! Вы молодец! Очень мне понравилось, когда вы сказали, что указ об открытии Школы-Студии МХАТ подписал товарищ Сталин. [Владлен Давыдов. Театр моей мечты (2004)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB%20%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6&docid=44683)
>
> ― Здравствуйте, здравствуйте! Вы молодец, Анатолий Карлович, что пришли! Суханов грузно поднялся из-за стола, вышел навстречу Журковскому, протягивая вперед руку для пожатия. [Андрей Белозеров. Чайка (2001)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB%20%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6&p=2&docid=43561)

Answer (score 2):

A russian friend told me "Molodets" wasn't a neutral expression: it is quite familiar, you can use it with a person you know well. Otherwise, it has a slightly patronizing connotation (ex: teacher talking to a pupil)...

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use it with business partners. It has patronizing obertones, for example a parent can say this to the kid, but not vice versa. Hardly even a boss can say this to an employee. The english equivalent is "smart girl", "smart boy".

Comment: ― Я слышал ваш разговор с моим коллегой. Вы молодец, конечно. Они в вас многое теряют, но только я должен сказать: я с вами всё-таки никак не согласен. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом, часть 2 (1943-1958)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%FB%20%EC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F6&docid=84742)

Comment: ok but so far in everyday's life I see people telling that to me and not always people I know and also it is true on the contrary that some people feel offended when been told that comment... again seems a war of civilization... I noticed 'pro-Russian' seem to use that term naturally while 'pro-West' seem always offended by the familiarity (and patronize symbols)  involved with it ... seems a strong cultural issue to me!

Comment: @KarlZorn there's one important note: you cannot always use "ты молодец". For example, you cannot come to your boss after a successful business deal that he signed, and tell him "ты (вы) молодец". Just because he doesn't need your approbation. But in some cases, a woman-employee can use this phrase when a man-employee can't. It strongly depends on a context and real people involved, their social positions, relations, sex...