# Specific use of the world "молодец"

Tags: словоупотребление, одним-словом, приветствия, connotation

Small question in music domain: if, for example, you have been hearing a wonderfull concert from a russian master player, can you tell him "молодец" or is it too familiar? Or, in this context, is it okay?

***EDIT: INFO:*** I finally asked a russian friend. She said it was informal, and used for someone well-known, or if not for someone hierarchically inferior... So "молодец" is obviously not a neutral expression! Thanks a lot to all for your help!

Comment: [russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/is-Молодец-молодцы́-always-a-familiar-expression](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/is-Молодец-молодцы́-always-a-familiar-expression)

Comment: "Hierarchically inferior" is a... curious way of putting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say it is not the best choice. "Молодец" has a slightly patronizing tone: it is OK to use it to your children and friends, maybe colleagues and subordinates.

However, if an adult person is not your friend/colleague and/or especially if you are in no position to judge their work (if you hear a concert from a virtuoso, chance is the guy is a much better critic of their own work)... then "Вы молодец" may express your affection but even with polite "Вы" it will still sound slightly out of place.

Answer (score 0):

"Молодец" will be okay almost in every situation, and here too. It is one of the most universal words. For musicians you can also use "виртуоз".